# How do I get the Text of a selected Item from a dropdown in MS PowerApps

Tags: text, automation, dropdown, patch, powerapps

I need help to get a text from a dropdown(dropDiretoria).

In the screenshot, i'm trying to get it to successfully execute a Patch to register a new user.
I've already tried using the following examples, none of them worked:
`dropDiretoria.Selected.Value dropDiretoria.SelectedText dropDiretoria.Selected dropDiretoria.Text Choices([@dropDiretoria]. Diretoria)`

It's important to notice that the Items are coming from a table in an Excel file and I simply need the text from the selection.
Thanks!

Comment: what screenshot?

Comment: Is it a drop down control or combo box control? What is `items` (data source) property of the control and what is the structure of data source property (column names, etc.)?